# Return an array containing prime numbers whose product is x

Tags: python, algorithm, list, primes

I am lost. My function works for some cases but there are some that it doesn't. For example, providing the number 110019 it should return an array [13,13,3,7,31] and it is not...

```
def primeFactorization(x):
    i=2
    array=[]
    for i in range(i,x+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            j=2
            for j in range(j,x+1):
                if i % j == 0:
                i=j
            array.append(i)
            product_value=1
            for j in array:
                product_value=j*product_value
                if product_value == x:
                    array.sort()
                    return array
    return []
```

Comment: You are not using arrays, you are using lists.

Comment: What's the logic you're trying to achieve? Do you have a source for the algorithm. It doesn't really make sense as it is.

Comment: modify list while iterating over them is always a bad idea, dont use `array.sort` into the `for j in array` loop

Comment: i'm trying to find all factors of the number. my first loop is going through each value from 2 to the value that we are trying to find factors for. the second loop is to turn let's say 4 into a 2, 6 into a 2, 9 into a 3. Any number that is a factor we are turning it into a prime by starting back from 2 again and looping through the numbers

Comment: Understood.  Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  For each number `i` that divides x, including x itself, you identify the lowest prime `j` that divides `i`.  This does *not* yield a prime factorisation of `x`.  Research on line a basic algorithm for prime factorisation.

Answer (score 3):

Some issues:

- the loop on `j` serves no purpose. The only time the `if` inside it is true, is when `i == j`, because after that `j` only increases. Furthermore, the assignment `i = j` changes nothing, as they are already equal when that happens
- Your code can never append the same value twice, yet that may be necessary.
- To restart calculating the product each time from scratch is a loss of time. You should do that incrementally as you append a new factor. It is even better to work from the opposite direction and *divide* `x` by each factor as you find it. That way you avoid ever finding non-prime factors.
- There is no use in sorting the list, since `i` increases in your code, so when you append `i` to the list, the list will always stay sorted.

Here is how it can work:

```
def primeFactorization(x):
    lst = []
    i = 2
    while x > 1:
        while x % i == 0:
            lst.append(i)
            x //= i
        i += 1
    return lst

print (primeFactorization(110019))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your logic is too convoluted, and you're tripping over yourself.  In particular, you identify factors too many times.  As a result, as you iterate through your nested loops, there are several copies of some factors in the factor list (which you named `array`), such that the product of that list is never the original number.  As a result, you never sort and return the array, and drop out to the final line of your function, returning   the empty list.

Instead of this algorithm, try using one of the known-correct methods.  Most of all, when you find a factor and put it into your list, divide `x` by the factor, and then continue factoring the quotient.  Your logic problems stem from working against the original number and then trying to determine whether the new component of the factor you've found.

Here's your code with some basic tracing prints:

```
def primeFactorization(x):
    i=2
    array=[]
    for i in range(i,x+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            print x, "divisible by", i
            j = 2
            for j in range(j,x+1):
                if i % j == 0:
                    print i, "divisible by", j, "resetting"
                    i = j
            array.append(i)
            print "New factor", array
            product_value = 1
            for j in array:
                product_value = j*product_value
                if product_value == x:
                    array.sort()
                    return array
    return []

print primeFactorization(110019)
```

Output:

```
110019 divisible by 3
3 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3]
110019 divisible by 7
7 divisible by 7 resetting
New factor [3, 7]
110019 divisible by 13
13 divisible by 13 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13]
110019 divisible by 21
21 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3]
110019 divisible by 31
31 divisible by 31 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31]
110019 divisible by 39
39 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3]
110019 divisible by 91
91 divisible by 7 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7]
110019 divisible by 93
93 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3]
110019 divisible by 169
169 divisible by 13 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13]
110019 divisible by 217
217 divisible by 7 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7]
110019 divisible by 273
273 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3]
110019 divisible by 403
403 divisible by 13 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13]
110019 divisible by 507
507 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13, 3]
110019 divisible by 651
651 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3]
110019 divisible by 1183
1183 divisible by 7 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7]
110019 divisible by 1209
1209 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7, 3]
110019 divisible by 2821
2821 divisible by 7 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7, 3, 7]
110019 divisible by 3549
3549 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3]
110019 divisible by 5239
5239 divisible by 13 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3, 13]
110019 divisible by 8463
8463 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3, 13, 3]
110019 divisible by 15717
15717 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3]
110019 divisible by 36673
36673 divisible by 7 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7]
110019 divisible by 110019
110019 divisible by 3 resetting
New factor [3, 7, 13, 3, 31, 3, 7, 3, 13, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7, 3, 7, 3, 13, 3, 3, 7, 3]
[]
```

Comment: So now we are getting all of the factors. Obviously duplicates. But then we want to try and find of ALL of those numbers, what can we we string together into an array whose product is x

Comment: @BrianGurka, as there is only one prime factorisation for each positive integer, and the product of those factors is the original number, there is only one solution.